# SSBO synchronization of writes

Tags: opengl

I have an OpenGL program which shows a (huge) lack of repeatability. In the fragment shader, I look for a specific condition. If that condition is met, I write to a SSBO the worldspace coordinates associated to that fragment, which I have kept from the vertex shader.

My problem is that, from one repetition of the program to a next one, the number of write operations to the SSBO does vary widely. Can it be that, if multiple shaders want to write to the SSBO at the same time, it would not always be done?

I do not read to the SSBO from the other shaders. So, it is not a problem of write/read synchronization. I read the SSBO only when I am back into the CPU application.

I use OpenGL 4.3 on a NVIDIA GTX645 card.

Comment: It's hard to see what the problem is without the source code.

Comment: It might take me some time but I will put something together to answer Nicol Bolas

Answer (score 0):

In the CPU application:

```
//Create one Shader Storage Buffer Object for vertices of detected points

            GLuint Detected_Vertices_SSBO;
            glGenBuffers(1,&Detected_Vertices_SSBO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,Detected_Vertices_SSBO);
            glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,(sizeN-NbTotalreflectionPoints.at(i))*sizeof(glm::vec4),NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Vertices SSBO at creation time.");
            QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);
            glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0,Detected_Vertices_SSBO);
            sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Vertices SSBO at binding time.");
            QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);

            //Create one Shader Storage Buffer Object for colors of detected points
            GLuint Detected_Vertices_Colors_SSBO;
            glGenBuffers(1,&Detected_Vertices_Colors_SSBO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,Detected_Vertices_Colors_SSBO);
            glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,(sizeN-NbTotalreflectionPoints.at(i))*sizeof(glm::vec4),NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Colors of Vertices SSBO at creation time.");
            QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);
            glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,1,Detected_Vertices_Colors_SSBO);
            sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Vertices Colors SSBO at binding time.");
            QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);

….
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 2*3+NbTargets1*12*3, NbPoints); //
                glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
                glFinish();
…
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Detected_Vertices_SSBO);
                glm::vec4 * SSBO_Position_ptr = (glm::vec4*)glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,GL_READ_ONLY);
                sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Vertices SSBO at mapping time.");
                QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);
                glFinish();
                glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Detected_Vertices_Colors_SSBO);
                glm::vec4 * SSBO_Color_ptr = (glm::vec4*)glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,GL_READ_ONLY);
                sprintf(OpenGLErrorMessage,"%s\n","Error on Vertices Colors SSBO at mapping time.");
                QueryForOpenGLErrors(OpenGLErrorMessage);
                glFinish();
```

Then, in the fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core
```

layout(early_fragment_tests) in;

```
// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec4 fragmentColor;
in vec4 worldspace;

//SSBO's for detected points and their colors
layout (binding=0, std430) coherent buffer detected_vertices_storage 
{
vec4 detected_vertices[];
}Positions;
layout (binding=1, std430) coherent buffer detected_vertices_colors_storage 
{
vec4 detected_vertices_colors[];
}Colors;



...




 Positions.detected_vertices[int(round(Condition * ((gl_FragCoord.y-0.5)*1024.0+(gl_FragCoord.x-0.5))/(1024.0*1024.0)*NbOfCosines))] = worldspace;
        Colors.detected_vertices_colors[int(round(Condition * ((gl_FragCoord.y-0.5)*1024.0+(gl_FragCoord.x-0.5))/(1024.0*1024.0)*NbOfCosines))] = color;
```

wherein Condition = 0 or 1.

I hope this will help. I am sorry to tell that I am still having much trouble with this formatting thing in stackoverflow. I must be too old!

Comment: I currently have a similar problem. Did you already solve this? My program everytime reads the same value in the mapped buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have fixed it.
After looking around on the web for a long time, I found out that, using `glDeleteBuffers(1, &_SSBO);` only might not always be enough for deleting the buffer: its name must be deleted as well. You would think the SSBO has been deleted and you can bind a new one by using `glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Detected_Vertices_SSBO);` but, from what I learned (and it worked), it may happen that the new binding will be made to the same SSBO name (or handle). In order to prevent this, make sure the SSBO is *unbinded* by using `glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0);` before binding a new one. The argument `0` in the command will make sure the SSBO has been really unbinded. Good luck!